# Flex VideoDisplay, Streaming FLV, pause/play causing rebuffer

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming

I am using FlashBuider 4.5 and the Flex 3.6 SDK.  I am using the VideoDisplay component to play an FLV from a streaming server (Red5 for those keeping score).

I am listening for VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE and VideoEvent.STATE_CHANGE to track what the player is up to.

I have a button that either calls .pause() if the player is running, or .play() if it's not.
Seems simple.

The first time I call .play(), I get something like I might expect:

onStateChange buffering
   onStateChange playing
   onPlayheadUpdate 0.067
   onPlayheadUpdate 0.232
   onPlayheadUpdate 0.488 ...

Then I call .pause():

onStateChange paused
   onPlayheadUpdate 3.2

that seems OK as well.  Then I call .play() again:

onStateChange buffering
   onStateChange playing
   onPlayheadUpdate 5
   onPlayheadUpdate 5.016
   onPlayheadUpdate 5.526 ...

First it's buffering, then it jumps ahead a couple of seconds.  I would have expected
it to pick right up where it left off.

Thoughts?  I can create a simple app with source if someone wants to look at that.
thanks
-Fred

Answer (score 0):

Just add this..

```
yourStream.bufferTime = 0;
```

This will end your buffer time and the stream will continue from where it left.

If thats what you dont want than please add a sample app with some code.